# Change App Service Plan does not working after move to another resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal, azure-resource-group, azure-service-plan

I have a strange issue in azure portal after moving my WebApp and App Service Plan to another resource group. After click to Change App Service Plan  I'm getting that info:

[image]

Application is worrking but I can't do anything with App Service Plan settings, moreover I can't event do this from powershell with using command:

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp -Name <webapp name> -ResourceGroupName <resource group name> -AppServicePlan <new app service plan>
```

Ticket submitted for support!

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I am assuming these "select app service plan" criteria are met -  

Exists in the same resource group ,
Exists in the same geographical region ,
Exists in the same webspace .
(A webspace is a logical construct in App Service that defines a grouping of server resources. A geographical region (such as West US) contains many webspaces in order to allocate customers who use App Service. Currently, you can't move App Service resources between webspaces.)    -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage

Comment: I also found similar issue - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/341e8fd0-9c43-4063-82a7-a219dd765d88/no-app-service-plans-found?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@komluk, As Avanish said that you can't move WebApp resources between web spaces and Moving web apps to App Service plans that are in data centers in different geographical locations is not supported.